# Expressing alternate in POSIX BRE?

Tags: regex, sed

Is it possible to write a POSIX BRE (no `\|` supported) that exactly matches two *arbitrary* strings? Say you want to match `this_string1_that` and `this_string2_that` as you would with `this_\(string1\|string2\)_that` without the `\|`. I guess it'll be rather ugly since `\(string1\)\{0,1\}\(string2\)\{0,1\}` matches "string1string2"

Edit: perhaps string1 / string2 is not the best example as they are close. The emphasis is on*arbitrary* strings, I am looking for an encoding algorithm for any two strings.

Edit1: find a BRE matching either of

- `this_TWWXP6rfgMwRbuG6ugDAMohq3FaQsI1mwThL47JoQrdMvIWTUGTdXi6dGzTqfRs_that`
- `this_oMfnmAwM8rKrsJniq5VGYFPs0EEBKKZgiHQhe5WXIVO8TieSspJ3GDnqpr8wDSU_that`

Comment: Does it have to be sed only? Can you not use other tools like awk?

Comment: I am actually curious for sed. Obviously I could use, I dunno, whatever, python, perl, ruby whatnot but I wanted to learn about sed / BRE.

Comment: Taking fact of existing GNU sed, you should consider solving this also in assembly. But question is however good  +1

Comment: This is a rather trivial problem in assembly. :) at least the ones I know (Z80 and x86) but I will risk the presumption it's easy in any architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With basic POSIX (BRE) `sed`, you could use:

```
/this_\(TWWXP...TqfRs\)\{0,1\}\(oMfn...8wDSU\)\{0,1\}_that/
```

where I replaced the centres of the strings `...` so you could see the overall structure of the command.  You would write out, or have your code write out, the full strings.  The regex would also match `this_Part1Part2_that`, but the chances of that occurring in your input non-maliciously are negligible. More seriously, it would match `this__that`, which is far less implausible as input.  You could use the pattern shown as a primary filter; you could then do a secondary filter on some data between the outer markers:

```
/this_\(TWWXP...TqfRs\)\{0,1\}\(oMfn...8wDSU\)\{0,1\}_that/ {
    /this_.\{63\}_that/ { ...process a genuine match... }
}
```

(I counted the lengths of the strings, and got 63 rather than 64, which surprised me a lot.)

However, this is a lot harder than writing out the two expressions twice, as in [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30961386/15168).

Answer (score 1):

Looking for something like this?

```
sed -n -e '/this_string1_that/p' -e '/this_string2_that/p' file
```

Comment: Sure, that's how I [solved](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2509496_sed.txt) this but the point is still learning BRE...

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't be done and the sed in question wouldn't support `{0,1}` either.